# Compactifications of $X$ and subalgebras of $BC(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a completely regular space. A subalgebra $\mathcal{A}$ of $BC(X)$ is called completely regular if (i) it is closed and contains the constant functions, and (ii) $\mathcal{A}\cap C(X,[0,1])$ separates points and closed sets (a family $\mathcal{F}\subset C(X,[0,1])$ is said to separate points and closed sets if for any closed set $E\subset X$ and $x\in E^{c}$, there exists $f\in\mathcal{F}$ such that $f(x)\notin\overline{f(E)}$).

(a) If $(Y,e)$ is a compactification of $X$, show that $\mathcal{A}_{Y}:=\{f\circ e:f\in C(Y)\}$ is a completely regular subalgebra of $BC(X)$.

(b) If $(Y,e)$ is the compactification of $X$ associated to $\mathcal{F}\subset C(X,[0,1])$, show that $\mathcal{A}_{Y}$ is the smallest closed subalgebra of $BC(X)$ that contains $\mathcal{F}$.

Related fact: If $B$ is a nonempty set and $X=[0,1]^{B}$, then the algebra generated by the coordinate maps $\pi_{\beta}:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ ($\beta\in B$) and the constant function 1 is dense in $C(X)$.

For (a), it is easy to see that $\mathcal{A}_{Y}$ contains the constant functions. I'm not sure about the other properties. It seems like I need to use the density of $e(X)$ in $Y$.

For (b), I let $\mathcal{A}$ be a closed subalgebra of $BC(X)$ containing $\mathcal{F}$. Then $\pi_{f}\circ e=f\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $f\in\mathcal{F}$. Using the fact stated above, the algebra $\mathcal{A}'$ generated by $\{\pi_{f}\circ e:f\in\mathcal{F}\}$ and the constant function 1 is dense in $C(X,[0,1])$. I'm not sure about the following: I said $\mathcal{A}'\subset\mathcal{A}$ so $\overline{A'}\subset\mathcal{A}$ since $\mathcal{A}$ is closed and it follows that $\mathcal{A}_{Y}\subset\mathcal{A}$ since $\mathcal{A}'$ is dense in $C(X,[0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

Some easy remarks:

For (a), indeed take $f_c \in C(Y)$ constant $c$, then $f_c \circ e$ is the constantly $c$ function on $X$, which is thus in $\mathcal{A}_Y$.

If $x \notin E$, $E \subset X$ closed, then $e(x) \notin \overline{e[E]}$, where the closure is taken in $Y$. Separate these by some $f \in C(Y,[0,1])$, as $Y$ is completely regular (even normal). Compose $f$ with $e$ and use that $f[\overline{e[E]}]$ is compact to see that the result separates $E$ and $x$.

Comment: And how should I see that $\mathcal{A}_{Y}$ is closed?