# Algebra of Functions and Compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $X$ be a completely regular topological space. Let $\mathscr F$ be a family of continuous functions mapping from $X$ to $[0,1]$ that separates points from closed sets, *i.e.*, whenever $C\subseteq X$ is closed and $x\notin C$, there must exist some $f\in\mathscr F$ such that $f(x)\notin\overline{f(C)}$. Consider $[0,1]^{\mathscr F}$ in the product topology. Suppose also that $e:X\to [0,1]^{\mathscr F}$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $e(X)$ and let $Y$ be the closure of $e(X)$ in $[0,1]^{\mathscr F}$ (the existence of such a homeomorphism is established). In other words, $(Y,e)$ is a compactification of $X$ generated by $\mathscr F$.

Let $$\mathscr A_Y\equiv\left\{f\circ e\,\big|\,f:Y\to\mathbb C,\text{ $f$ continuous}\right\}$$
and
$$\mathscr A\equiv\overline{\bigcap_{\substack{\mathscr C\in BC(X)\\\mathscr C\text{ is an algebra}\\\mathscr F\subseteq \mathscr C}}\mathscr C},$$
where $BC(X)$ is the family of bounded, continuous, complex-valued functions on $X$. This way, $\mathscr A$ is the smallest closed subalgebra of $BC(X)$ that contains $\mathscr F$. On the other hand, $\mathscr A_Y$ is the set of such continuous complex-valued functions on $X$ that the associated complex-valued function on $e(X)$ can be extended continuously to $Y\equiv\overline{e(X)}$.

**Claim:** $\mathscr A=\mathscr A_Y$.

I showed $\mathscr A\subseteq \mathscr A_Y$, but the other direction seems to be elusive. The following facts that are supposed to be used are also established:

- $\mathscr A_Y$ is a closed subalgebra of $BC(X)$ (in the uniform metric) and contains all constant functions.
- Let $$\mathscr L\equiv\{\pi_f:[0,1]^{\mathscr F}\to[0,1]\}_{f\in\mathscr F}\bigcup\{1\}.$$ That is, $\mathscr L$ is the collection of coordinate maps together with the constant *function* $1$. It can be shown (using the Stone–Weierstrass theorem) that $$\overline{\bigcap_{\substack{\mathscr D\subseteq BC\left([0,1]^{\mathscr F}\right)\\\mathscr D\text{ is an algebra}\\\mathscr L\subseteq\mathscr D}}\mathscr D}=BC\left([0,1]^{\mathscr F}\right).$$
  That is, the smallest subalgebra of $BC([0,1]^{\mathscr F})$ containing $\mathscr L$ is dense in $BC([0,1]^{\mathscr F})$.

My basic idea was to show that
$$\overline{\bigcap_{\substack{\mathscr D\subseteq BC\left([0,1]^{\mathscr F}\right)\\\mathscr D\text{ is an algebra}\\\mathscr L\subseteq\mathscr D}}\{h\circ e\,|\,h\in\mathscr D\}}$$ contains $\mathscr A_Y$ and is contained in $\mathscr A$. I managed to prove the first assertion (using Tietze's extension theorem to go from $Y$ to $[0,1]^{\mathscr F}$) but I am stuck with the second.

I conjecture also that given the results I have so far, it would be very helpful to somehow show that $\mathscr A$ must contain the constant functions (intuitively, if $\mathscr F$ separates points from closed sets, then its structure must be so rich that it can “span” the constant functions under the algebraic operations of addition, multiplication, and multiplication by a constant, so that any algebra that contains $\mathscr F$ must also contain the constant functions). I am stuck with proving this assertion as well.

Disclaimer: This is from Folland (1999, Exercise 4.73(c)). [This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340871/compactifications-of-x-and-subalgebras-of-bcx) is asking for the same question, but I did not find that discussion satisfying. I would appreciate any hint or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The statement is *not* true. It is not difficult to come up with a counterexample of a space containing two distinct points endowed with the discrete topology. Then, the singleton collection containing a function whose value is 0 at one point and 1 at the other separates points and closed sets. However, its generated closed algebra does *not* contain the constant functions.

The claim becomes true, however, if one redefines $\mathscr A$ to be the smallest closed subalgebra of $BC(X)$ that contains $\mathscr F$ *and the constant functions*. If anyone is interested, I will type up the proof.